# Lodash searching object properties and modifying value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to loop through an object, looking for values defined in an array. The properties are typically ones with a epoch timestamp.

Once a property is found, I want to convert that properties' value to human readable.

```
may myArray = ["dob", "movingDate"];

var myObj = {
    prop1: "hi",
    prop2: "goodnight",
    prop3: "welcome",
    prop4: "now",
    name: "Alfred",
    age: 46,
    dob: 3165300688,
    gender: "female",
    movingDate: 1461233587
}

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {    
    var exists = _.has(myObj, myArray[i]);
}
```

Which correctly finds the properties if present, but how can I get the properties value?

I can fix the above using standard `Object.Keys` notation, but I am trying to do this with `lodash` and `moment`.

Once I have the property, I can use moment to convert via:

```
prop = moment.format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

Should I be using:

```
_.pick
```

Or:

```
_.update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need lodash here, simple `forEach` with [in-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to test for property presence could be enough:

```
myArray.forEach(function(value) {
  if (value in myObj) {
    myObj[value] = moment.unix(myObj[value]).format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the property value by simply doing

```
myArray.forEach(function(val){
  if ( myObj.hasOwnProperty(val) )
  {
    myObj[val] = formatDate(myObj[val]);
  }
});
```

Assuming that you have a method formatDate to format timestamp to date format using moment (or any of your fav library)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function formatDate(val) { return new Date(val); }

_.assign({}, myObj,
  _(myObj)
    .pick(myArray)
    .mapValues(formatDate)
    .value());
```

Note, that the call to [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) will actually create a new object instead of mutating `myObj`. This is because of the first argument - `{}`. If you need to modify the `myObj` reference, just remove this first argument.

The value that gets assigned is the result of picking values based on `myArray` and [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick). Since this returns an object, we want to use the [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) function for format the dates - the `formatDate()` function can return anything.

Comment: Immutability is definitly the way to go. +1